# capturing relevant user requests using filter/interceptors

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, web-applications

I am capturing URLs requested for my website. I need to see what all pages were requested from my website.

To achieve this I created a basic filter, and started logging page requests from there.

Now, this filter catches all the requests specific to a page.

> For e.g. *abc.com/page1*, *abc.com/resources/myjs.js*, etc.

My problem is that for each page request, subsequent resources(js,css) are requested too. I want to capture only the relevant requests.

Right now, I check for patterns like `/resources` to ignore such requests, but I am looking for a more clean approach.

Also, will interceptors be more useful here?
I have seen filter patterns as well. But those are not useful, since I would have to create patterns for my filter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture the urls accessed from your website, you can configure spring boot to generate access logs in following way until you don't want more advance information:

```
server.tomcat.accesslog.directory=/logs/  #absolute directory path for log files\
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=false #Enable access log.  
server.tomcat.accesslog.pattern=any_pattern # log string format pattern for access logs.
```

To perform any operation based on any request pattern, you can go ahead with filters.
I'm using filters for such requirements in following way:

```
    public class CustomFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String url = request.getRequestURI();
        if (url.startsWith("/resources/")) {
            //your business logic
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, for logging I'll be storing the logs to a remote db.

Comment: Okay, I have edited my answer. Please check if it solves your problem.

Comment: I am trying to find a solution which prevents me from doing this. Is there any approach where I wouldnt have to write logic to check for resource requests.

Comment: I guess no. Because even when you configure spring security for endpoint authentication then it internally uses same approach to distinguish between other request urls.